# How to return a string from select statement in sqlite in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT accno from AccountMaster where pan = " + pan;

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

int accno = 0;
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
accno=cursor.getInt(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to make sure that the column you want to fetch stores text. In that case use

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT accno from AccountMaster where pan = " + pan;
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
   String value = cursor.getString(indexNumber)
}
```

Otherwise, if the column stores an int, you can do this.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT accno from AccountMaster where pan = " + pan;
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
   int value = cursor.getInt(indexNumber)
}
```

You can as well convert your return int value to String value using

```
String mValue = String.valueOf(intValue);
```

Comment: Thank you so much...but I am facing a certain problem with that.... I made "accno" as integer.....so return value must be an integer.....but actually I am confused at getInt(indexno) function...will you please tell me what indexno means? As index no of accno in table is 0...thn is this that no that I should give as a parameter or what ?

Comment: Actually I want to return it the accno....for example it should return account no like 1006